# Django: select option with default field in template

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I want to try select my default field in select option forms. My main form here is `form` and `form.status` gets all user possibility status and `user_form.initial.status` gets user current status:

```
<div class="col-lg-9 select mb-3">
    <select name="status" ng-model='discussionsSelect' class="custom-select form-control">
        {% for status in form.status %}
            <option value="{{user_form.initial.status}}" 
                {% if status == user_form.initial.status %}selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{status}}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</div>
```

But it is not selected as default.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
<select ... name="status">
{% for value, label in form.fields.status.choices %}
    <option value="{{ value }}"{% if user_form.status.value == value %} selected{% endif %}>{{ label }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you seems true but in my case when I put `for loop` in `<select>` it doesn't print outputs.

Comment: But out of `<select>` everything is true

Comment: What is your `user_form.status.value` and? Share your code that you are now use.

Comment: I got the answer. I should do it: `{% if account.status == value %}`. Thank you very much